# react query returning empty object for data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-query

I am trying to abstract away my react/tanstack query.

I have a custom hook like the following:

```
const useGamesApi = () => {
  const upcomingGamesQuery = useQuery(
    ["upcoming", date],
    async () => {
      const ret = await apiGetUpcomingGames(date);
      return ret;
    },
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setGames(data);
      },
    }
  );

  return {
    games: upcomingGamesQuery,
  };
};

export default useGamesApi;
```

I am trying to consume my API as follows:

```
const [games, setGames] = useState<Game[]>([]);
const gamesApi = useGamesApi();
useEffect(() => {
    setGames(gamesApi.games.data);
  }, []);
```

This leads to compilation errors and also the value of my games state variable remains an empty array, as if the useEffect never ran.

Basically I am trying to abstract away my react query to provide a simplified way of interacting with it for my components, whilst also giving it a chance to modify the parameter of the date, so that I can be able to set until which date I would like to query.

What would be the correct (compilation vise) and idiomatic way of doing this with react?

(note I am using this in a react native project, not sure if it counts.)

Answer (score 0):

1. As per rules , You need to add all the variables used inside `useEffect` as dependency so that it reacts once the value is changed.
2. You don't really need `useEffect` for you scenario. It is used to cause side effects.  simply do it like :

```
 const games: Game[] = gamesApi?.games?.data;
  
  const games: Game[] = gamesApi?.games?.data || []; // incase you need default value
```